# What would prevent the Azure Function Runtime from starting in an ILB ASE deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-envrmnt, internal-load-balancer

I have an ILB ASE with a function app deployed. I have a JumpBox configured with the custom domain in its HOSTS file and set up to trust my self-signed certificate for both the `function.custom` and `function.scm.custom` domains. This setup has allowed me to get past the typical error where function storage cannot be accessed.

Now, however, I face a new issue:

[image]

What could be causing this, and how can I resolve it?

Additional notes:

- CORS is currently set to `*` while we debug this
- I can connect to the Kudu console for the function app fine with the deployment credentials
- But the function URL itself returns:

[image]

*Update*: GitHub issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4011

Comment: Kindly open an issue and provide details about your Function App at our GitHub repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/new and we will investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks @LingToh https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4011

Comment: I have responded. The platform and the worker seems to be healthy but the host process can't seem to load your Function code. Could you check if your are able to run your Function locally?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for slow reply - managing a release. Will review this and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at an F12 Trace in browser do you see any failed calls with a status code greater than 399?

Comment: 399 - no. A long list of 500/503.

Comment: The 500s and 503s seem to indicate the host not being able to start. Based on what I'm seeing from the backend logs (I'm an MS Employee), it looks like your function host is not starting up. Have you deployed code to this function? Can you try removing all your code and just keeping the host.json and see if your function code runs with the bare bones deployment?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for slow reply - managing a release. Will review this and get back to you.